# javascript array remove by key

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have been looking how to remove a record from an array by key, but only found when the key is numberic, the problem is, I don't have a numberic key.

I build an array like this:

```
var obj = [];

obj.key1 = {name: "John", room: 1234};
obj.key2 = {name: "Jim", room: 1234};
```

Now the result of obj is

```
[key1: Object, key2: Object]
```

Which is exactly what I expect.

Now I am wondering, how would I completely remove key1 from obj? I couldn't find anything about this when the key is alphabetic.

Comment: `Delete obj["key1"]`

Comment: An array has always a numeric key.

Comment: It's not normal practice to add properties to arrays like that. It *works*, because arrays are objects, but there's no point using an array if you're not using regular integer indices (keys). You should be using a plain object rather than an array.

Comment: "I don't have a numberic key" — Why are you using an array then?

Comment: Yes dupe is about object, but even arrays are objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in very easy way with ES6:

```
delete(obj["key1"])
```

Comment: That's not an ES6 feature, that's old-school JS. By the way, the parentheses aren't required, `delete` isn't a function.